# Changing the program

Tags: javascript, java, android, google-glass

[uploading image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxvCh.jpg)I am trying to make a program using http to upload a picture directly to the server from glass but i am not able to do it the code I have can only upload one picture that is already there but not the picture i have taken in the glass can someone please verify the code and tell me how to change it in such a way that i can upload the pictures i have taken directly

logcat:

```
06-10 15:07:43.813: D/GCM(718): GcmService start Intent { act=com.google.android.checkin.CHECKIN_COMPLETE flg=0x10 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService (has extras) } com.google.android.checkin.CHECKIN_COMPLETE
06-10 15:07:43.844: I/GlassUserEventService[42357a28](1071): Performance stats: [object: com.google.common.logging.GlassExtensionsNano$GlassUserEventPerformanceStats {    batteryChargeWhenFullUah_: 604000    totalKernelMs_: 8848030    totalBytesSent_: 1218965    bitField0_: 16383    boardTemperatureMilliCentigrade_: 40970    frequencyScalingGovernor_: 0    availableMemoryKb_: 989140    isLowMemory_: false    networkType_: 1    qpassedFractional_: 46921    qpassedInteger_: 17182    reportedSoc_: 99    batteryTemperatureMilliCentigrade_: 26800    batteryStateOfChargeUah_: 595000    totalMemoryKb_: 1475504    unknownFieldData: null    cachedSize: -1}]
06-10 15:07:53.836: I/NativeAppVoiceMenuHelper(865): Installed packages changed; invalidating trigger cache
06-10 15:07:53.836: V/FormattingLoggers(865): TimingData [count=780, sinceCreation=14174171ms, spentLogging=272ms].
06-10 15:07:53.836: W/Searchables(498): No global search activity found
06-10 15:07:53.852: I/InputReader(498): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
06-10 15:07:53.860: V/GmsNetworkLocationProvi(1181): DISABLE
06-10 15:07:53.860: D/PackageBroadcastService(816): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED and uri=com.google.android.gms
06-10 15:07:53.906: E/GCoreFlp(1181): Bound FusedProviderService with LocationManager
06-10 15:07:53.906: V/GmsNetworkLocationProvi(1181): ENABLE
06-10 15:07:53.914: V/GmsNetworkLocationProvi(1181): onSetRequest: ProviderRequestUnbundled, reportLocation is true and interval is 86400000
06-10 15:07:53.914: V/GmsNetworkLocationProvi(1181): SET-REQUEST
06-10 15:07:53.914: V/GmsNetworkLocationProvi(1181): in Handler: ProviderRequestUnbundled, reportLocation is true and interval is 86400000
06-10 15:07:56.149: W/BluetoothAdapter(773): getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
06-10 15:07:56.149: D/BluetoothSocket(773): connect(), SocketState: INIT, mPfd: {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[97]}
```

---

```
package com.morkout.nbsocial;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class HTTPRequestActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String TAG = "HTTPRequestActivity";
    TextView mTvInfo;
    String mWhat;
    HttpURLConnection mUrlConnection;
    String mResult;

    protected void onResume () {
        super.onResume();       
    }

    protected void onPause () {
        super.onPause();
    }   

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mTvInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        mWhat = intent.getStringExtra("WHAT");
        Log.i(TAG,  "WHAT="+mWhat);

        mTvInfo.setText("Making HTTP "+ mWhat + " request...");

        new HTTPRequest().execute();
    }

    // Async task class to make HTTP Get, Post and upload 
    private class HTTPRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {           
            try {
                if (mWhat.equalsIgnoreCase("GET")) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "GET");                  

                    // get json via YouTube API
                    URL url = new URL("http://Google.com");
                    mUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)            url.openConnection();
                    InputStream in = new     BufferedInputStream(mUrlConnection.getInputStream());
                    int ch;
                    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
                    while ((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
                        b.append((char) ch);
                    }

                    mResult = new String(b);
                    in.close();
                }
                else if (mWhat.equalsIgnoreCase("POST")) {
                    URL url = new URL("http://morkout.com/glass/posttest.php");
                    mUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    mUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    String urlParameters = "email=kandyala.komal-chowdary@stud.th-deg.de&name=komal chowdary&pwd=1234567&vcode=2014";
                    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(mUrlConnection.getOutputStream());
                    writer.write(urlParameters);
                    writer.flush();                 

                    InputStream in = new     BufferedInputStream(mUrlConnection.getInputStream());
                    int ch;
                    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
                    while ((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
                        b.append((char) ch);
                    }

                    mResult = new String(b);

                    in.close();
                    writer.close();
                }
                else if (mWhat.equalsIgnoreCase("UPLOAD")) {
                    int serverResponseCode = 0;        
                    File sourceFile = new File(copyAsset("marchmadness.png"));
                    DataOutputStream dos = null;  
                    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
                    String twoHyphens = "--";
                    String boundary = "*****";
                    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
                    byte[] buffer;
                    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 

                    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
                        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" +sourceFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                        URL url = new URL("http://www.morkout.com/glass/upload.php");
                        mUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                        mUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        mUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                        mUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Filedata", sourceFile.getName()); 

                        dos = new DataOutputStream(mUrlConnection.getOutputStream());

                        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data;     name=Filedata;filename="+ sourceFile.getName()  + lineEnd);
                        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                        // create a buffer of  maximum size
                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                        // read file and write it into form...
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                        while (bytesRead > 0) {

                            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);    
                            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                        }

                        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                        // Responses from the server (code and message)
                        serverResponseCode = mUrlConnection.getResponseCode();
                        String serverResponseMessage = mUrlConnection.getResponseMessage();

                        Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                            + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                        if(serverResponseCode == 200) {
                            Log.v(TAG, "File Upload Completed.");


                            InputStream is = mUrlConnection.getInputStream();
                            int ch;

                            StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
                            while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
                                b.append((char) ch);
                            }

                            final String uploadedFilename = b.toString();
                            Log.v(TAG, "uploaded file at http://www.morkout.com/glass/uploads/" + uploadedFilename);
                            mResult = "uploaded file at http://www.morkout.com/glass/uploads/" + uploadedFilename;
                            is.close();
                        }

                        fileInputStream.close();
                        dos.close();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }           
            finally {
                if (mUrlConnection != null)
                    mUrlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            return null;
        }       

        String copyAsset(String filename) {
            final String PATH =     Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/nbsocial/";
            File dir = new File(PATH);
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "ERROR: Creation of directory " + PATH + " on sdcard failed");
                    return null;
                } else {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Created directory " + PATH + " on sdcard");
                }
            }

            if (!(new File( PATH + filename).exists())) {
                Log.v(TAG, "copying file " + filename);
                try {

                    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
                    InputStream in = assetManager.open(filename);
                    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(PATH + filename);

                    // Transfer bytes from in to out
                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                    int len;
                    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                        out.write(buf, 0, len);
                    }
                    in.close();
                    out.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Was unable to copy " + filename + e.toString());
                    return null;
                }
            }       
            return PATH + filename; 
        }       


        @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.w(TAG, "onPostExecute");
            mTvInfo.setText(mResult);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your logcat output also

Comment: sorry for saying this but i have no idea how to post logcat, i can view it though but ...

Comment: you can do Ctrl+c for copying it, and than you can past relevant content here in your question.

Comment: but its not possible to find one they are going on like 100's at a time and i am not able to locate what i want

Comment: but i can post the pictures of what i am getting as an output

Comment: i have posted the logcat above but i am not sure if it is enough @shriduttkothari